# Python- displaying frequent words in a table and skipping certain words

Tags: python, collections, frequency, prettytable

Currently I'm doing a frequency analysis on a text file that shows the top 100 commonly used words in the text file. Currently I'm using this code:

```
from collections import Counter
import re
words = re.findall(r'\w+', open('tweets.txt').read().lower())
print Counter(words).most_common (100)
```

The code above works and the outputs are:

```
[('the', 1998), ('t', 1829), ('https', 1620), ('co', 1604), ('to', 1247), ('and', 1053), ('in', 957), ('a', 899), ('of', 821), ('i', 789), ('is', 784), ('you', 753), ('will', 654), ('for', 601), ('on', 574), ('thank', 470), ('be', 455), ('great', 447), ('hillary', 440), ('we', 390), ('that', 373), ('s', 363), ('it', 346), ('with', 345), ('at', 333), ('me', 327), ('are', 311), ('amp', 290), ('clinton', 288), ('trump', 287), ('have', 286), ('our', 264), ('realdonaldtrump', 256), ('my', 244), ('all', 237), ('crooked', 236), ('so', 233), ('by', 226), ('this', 222), ('was', 217), ('people', 216), ('has', 210), ('not', 210), ('just', 210), ('america', 204), ('she', 190), ('they', 188), ('trump2016', 180), ('very', 180), ('make', 180), ('from', 175), ('rt', 170), ('out', 169), ('he', 168), ('her', 164), ('makeamericagreatagain', 164), ('join', 161), ('as', 158), ('new', 157), ('who', 155), ('again', 154), ('about', 145), ('no', 142), ('get', 138), ('more', 137), ('now', 136), ('today', 136), ('president', 135), ('can', 134), ('time', 123), ('media', 123), ('vote', 117), ('but', 117), ('am', 116), ('bad', 116), ('going', 115), ('maga', 112), ('u', 112), ('many', 110), ('if', 110), ('country', 108), ('big', 108), ('what', 107), ('your', 105), ('cnn', 105), ('never', 104), ('one', 101), ('up', 101), ('back', 99), ('jobs', 98), ('tonight', 97), ('do', 97), ('been', 97), ('would', 94), ('obama', 93), ('tomorrow', 88), ('said', 88), ('like', 88), ('should', 87), ('when', 86)]
```

However, I want to display it in a table form with a header "Word" and "Count". I've tried using the `prettytable` package and came up with this:

```
from collections import Counter
import re
import prettytable

words = re.findall(r'\w+', open('tweets.txt').read().lower())

for label, data in ('Word', words):
    pt = prettytable(field_names=[label, 'Count'])
    c = Counter(data)
    [pt.add_row(kv) for kv in c.most_common() [:100] ]
    pt.align [label], pt.align['Count'] = '1', 'r'
    print pt
```

It gives me `ValueError: too many values to unpack`. My question is, whats wrong with my code and is there a way to display the data using `prettytable`? Also, how can I mend my code?

Bonus question: Is there a way to leave out certain words while counting the frequency? e.g skip the words: and, if, of etc etc

Thanks.

Comment: What line is the error on? Update the question.

Comment: What is `('Word', words)`?

Comment: the error is in this line "for label, data in ('Word', words):"

Comment: Sorry am new to python, Word is the header label and 'words' are the words themselves (e.g. they,make, get, etc etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how you expected the `for` loop you wrote to work. The error you are getting is because you are attempting to iterate over the tuple `('Word', words)` which has two elements. The statement `for label, data in ('Word', words)` attempts to assign `'W'` to `label`, `'o'` to `data` and ends up with `'r'` and `'d'` left over on the first iteration. Perhaps you meant to zip the items together instead? But then why are you making a new table for each word?

Here is a rewritten version:

```
from collections import Counter
import re, prettytable

words = re.findall(r'\w+', open('tweets.txt').read().lower())
c = Counter(words)
pt = prettytable.PrettyTable(['Words', 'Counts'])
pt.align['Words'] = 'l'
pt.align['Counts'] = 'r'
for row in c.most_common(100):
    pt.add_row(row)
print pt
```

To skip elements in the most common count, you can simply discard them from the counter before calling `most_common`. One easy way to do that is to define a list of invalid words, and then to filter them out with a dict comprehension:

```
bad_words = ['the', 'if', 'of']
c = Counter({k: v for k, v in c.items() if k not in bad_words})
```

Alternatively, you can do the filtering on the list of words before you make a counter out of it:

```
words = filter(lambda x: x not in bad_words, words)
```

I prefer operating on the counter because that requires less work since the data has already been aggregated. Here is the combined code for reference:

```
from collections import Counter
import re, prettytable

bad_words = ['the', 'if', 'of']
words = re.findall(r'\w+', open('tweets.txt').read().lower())

c = Counter(words)
c = Counter({k: v for k, v in c.items() if k not in bad_words})

pt = prettytable.PrettyTable(['Words', 'Counts'])
pt.align['Words'] = 'l'
pt.align['Counts'] = 'r'
for row in c.most_common(100):
    pt.add_row(row)

print(pt)
```

Comment: i got an error from your code. File "test4.py", line 7, in <module>
    pt.set_field_names(["Words", "Counts"])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\prettytable.py", line 217, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: set_field_names

Comment: @Vin23. I fixed that.

Comment: @Vin23. The docs are a bit out of date for the library, my first version was based off of that.

Comment: This answer has only one advantage over loics, which is that it makes a table of the 100 most common words *after* the skips were removed, not before.

Answer (score 2):

Is it what you are trying to do ?

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

x = PrettyTable(["Words", "Counts"])

L = [('the', 1998), ('t', 1829), ('https', 1620), ('co', 1604), ('to', 1247), ('and', 1053), ('in', 957), ('a', 899), ('of', 821), ('i', 789), ('is', 784), ('you', 753), ('will', 654), ('for', 601), ('on', 574), ('thank', 470), ('be', 455), ('great', 447), ('hillary', 440), ('we', 390), ('that', 373), ('s', 363), ('it', 346), ('with', 345), ('at', 333), ('me', 327), ('are', 311), ('amp', 290), ('clinton', 288), ('trump', 287), ('have', 286), ('our', 264), ('realdonaldtrump', 256), ('my', 244), ('all', 237), ('crooked', 236), ('so', 233), ('by', 226), ('this', 222), ('was', 217), ('people', 216), ('has', 210), ('not', 210), ('just', 210), ('america', 204), ('she', 190), ('they', 188), ('trump2016', 180), ('very', 180), ('make', 180), ('from', 175), ('rt', 170), ('out', 169), ('he', 168), ('her', 164), ('makeamericagreatagain', 164), ('join', 161), ('as', 158), ('new', 157), ('who', 155), ('again', 154), ('about', 145), ('no', 142), ('get', 138), ('more', 137), ('now', 136), ('today', 136), ('president', 135), ('can', 134), ('time', 123), ('media', 123), ('vote', 117), ('but', 117), ('am', 116), ('bad', 116), ('going', 115), ('maga', 112), ('u', 112), ('many', 110), ('if', 110), ('country', 108), ('big', 108), ('what', 107), ('your', 105), ('cnn', 105), ('never', 104), ('one', 101), ('up', 101), ('back', 99), ('jobs', 98), ('tonight', 97), ('do', 97), ('been', 97), ('would', 94), ('obama', 93), ('tomorrow', 88), ('said', 88), ('like', 88), ('should', 87), ('when', 86)]


for e in L:
    x.add_row([e[0],e[1]])

print x
```

Here is the result:

```
+-----------------------+--------+
|         Words         | Counts |
+-----------------------+--------+
|          the          |  1998  |
|           t           |  1829  |
|         https         |  1620  |
|           co          |  1604  |
|           to          |  1247  |
|          and          |  1053  |
|           in          |  957   |
|           a           |  899   |
|           of          |  821   |
|           i           |  789   |
|           is          |  784   |
|          you          |  753   |
|          will         |  654   |
|          for          |  601   |
|           on          |  574   |
|         thank         |  470   |
|           be          |  455   |
|         great         |  447   |
|        hillary        |  440   |
|           we          |  390   |
|          that         |  373   |
|           s           |  363   |
|           it          |  346   |
|          with         |  345   |
|           at          |  333   |
|           me          |  327   |
|          are          |  311   |
|          amp          |  290   |
|        clinton        |  288   |
|         trump         |  287   |
|          have         |  286   |
|          our          |  264   |
|    realdonaldtrump    |  256   |
|           my          |  244   |
|          all          |  237   |
|        crooked        |  236   |
|           so          |  233   |
|           by          |  226   |
|          this         |  222   |
|          was          |  217   |
|         people        |  216   |
|          has          |  210   |
|          not          |  210   |
|          just         |  210   |
|        america        |  204   |
|          she          |  190   |
|          they         |  188   |
|       trump2016       |  180   |
|          very         |  180   |
|          make         |  180   |
|          from         |  175   |
|           rt          |  170   |
|          out          |  169   |
|           he          |  168   |
|          her          |  164   |
| makeamericagreatagain |  164   |
|          join         |  161   |
|           as          |  158   |
|          new          |  157   |
|          who          |  155   |
|         again         |  154   |
|         about         |  145   |
|           no          |  142   |
|          get          |  138   |
|          more         |  137   |
|          now          |  136   |
|         today         |  136   |
|       president       |  135   |
|          can          |  134   |
|          time         |  123   |
|         media         |  123   |
|          vote         |  117   |
|          but          |  117   |
|           am          |  116   |
|          bad          |  116   |
|         going         |  115   |
|          maga         |  112   |
|           u           |  112   |
|          many         |  110   |
|           if          |  110   |
|        country        |  108   |
|          big          |  108   |
|          what         |  107   |
|          your         |  105   |
|          cnn          |  105   |
|         never         |  104   |
|          one          |  101   |
|           up          |  101   |
|          back         |   99   |
|          jobs         |   98   |
|        tonight        |   97   |
|           do          |   97   |
|          been         |   97   |
|         would         |   94   |
|         obama         |   93   |
|        tomorrow       |   88   |
|          said         |   88   |
|          like         |   88   |
|         should        |   87   |
|          when         |   86   |
+-----------------------+--------+
```

**EDIT 1:** If you want to leave out certain you could do something like that:

```
for e in L:
    if e[0]!="and" or e[0]!="if" or e[0]!="of":
        x.add_row([e[0],e[1]])
```

**EDIT 2**: to sum up:

```
from collections import Counter
import re

words = re.findall(r'\w+', open('tweets.txt').read().lower())
counts = Counter(words).most_common (100)

from prettytable import PrettyTable

x = PrettyTable(["Words", "Counts"])

skip_list = ['and','if','or'] # see joe's comment

for e in counts:
    if e[0] not in skip_list:
        x.add_row([e[0],e[1]])

print x
```

Comment: Yes, something like this. but is it possible to not have the long lists of different words?

Comment: You mean that you want to pick each data from the text file and put it directly in the table ? Can you give me a link of the text file ? I want to see how the data is arranged in the file.

Comment: You can define `skip_list = [‘and’, ‘if’, ‘or’]` and `if e[0] not in skip_list:`

Comment: Of course why didn't I thought about this ... Joe's answer is better if you want to leave out specific words

Comment: Sorry I have to admit that I do not really see how to help you not to use a list, this is the first time I use regex and collection.

Comment: Off topic: I am wondering, why are you doing that ? I know that psychologists use that method to study the behaviour of some people. Or are you just interested in programming?

Comment: because the tweets that ive gathered in the txt file is from one certain user. the code u wrote allows me to just change one line in order for the code for a different user.

Comment: `[e[0], e[1]]` -> `e`

Comment: Also, this version will create a table with < 100 elements because it will remove the skip words after calling `most_common`.

Comment: Yes I didn't think about that. @Vin23 you should follow what MadPhysicist did.